# Call a function inside Wrap contain list of elements in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to call a function inside Wrap content. My requirement is to call this function before the wrap content is loaded.

```dart
 void checkFund(){}

    Wrap(
    children: entList
        .map((element) => Padding(
    
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0, bottom: 5),
    
    child: element['isAcq']
    ? Acquisition('${element['ele']}')
    : element['isPartner']
    ? GestureDetector(
    // onTap: () {
    //   print('partner');
    // },
    child: NewPartnerShip(
    '${element['ele']}',
   )
    : element['isFunding']
    ?
    Funding('${element['ele']??'NA'}',
   ))
    .toList(),
    )
```

Comment: Can you include sample data and proper snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn `expression body =>` into a `block body`

```dart
void checkFund(){}

    Wrap(
    children: entList
        .map((element) { 
         checkFund();
          retrun Padding(
    
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0, bottom: 5),
    
    child: element['isAcq']
    ? Acquisition('${element['ele']}')
    : element['isPartner']
    ? GestureDetector(
    // onTap: () {
    //   print('partner');
    // },
    child: NewPartnerShip(
    '${element['ele']}',
   )
    : element['isFunding']
    ?
    Funding('${element['ele']??'NA'}',
   ))
    .toList(),
    );
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it by using function to get some widget E.g.

```
... 
child: _myFancyWidget(),
... 
Widget _myFancyWidget() {
   checkFund();
   return  Wrap( ... );
}
...
void checkFund(){}
...
```